# Native Base: Cannot create an Accordion/Collapse Component

Tags: react-native, accordion, native-base

I realize Accordion is on older version of Native base, but I don't see anywhere in docs that it will not work in newer versions. I have tried running the example code in React Native Expo boiler place app and nothing renders for me.

```
let dataArray = [{title:'title',content:'content'}];

const renderAccordionHeader = (item, expanded) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{"example title"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

return (<>
  <Container>
      <Accordion dataArray={dataArray} renderHeader={renderAccordionHeader}/>
  </Container>
</>);
```

What is the equivalent Accordion component in the newest Native Base version? I see that Collapse is in version 3, but first link on Google for "Native Base Collapse" returns 404: https://docs.nativebase.io/3.0.x/blocked-components

I've tried every example in the Native Base docs to no avail. I have also attempted this solution: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3413

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you find any fix for this? I am also having same issue.

Comment: I had to use the react-native-collapsible/Accordion in the end: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible

Answer (score 0):

Accordion doesn't appear to be in the newest Native base version. It was removed from the docs in version [v3.0.0-next.37](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases?page=11).  So I observe 3 options:

1. [react-native-collapsible](https://npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible). (I ended up using - works great)
2. Downgrade to version before 3.0
3. Create your own Accordion component if you do not want to use a library.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be in v3.4 after all , but not mentioned in documentation
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/4756#issuecomment-1316676933